# django-geoext sample cannot import name execute_manager

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

hello I wanto to run this [example](https://github.com/capooti/django-geoext-sample) django-geoext from GitHub but I take error `ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager`

any idea ho to can fix that ?

code of manage.py :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core.management import execute_manager
import imp
try:
    imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.
except ImportError:
    import sys
    sys.stderr.write("Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing %r. It appears you've customized things.\nYou'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.\n" % __file__)
    sys.exit(1)

import settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    execute_manager(settings)
```

error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/username/Desktop/django-geoext-sample-master/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: cannot import name execute_manager
```